# Max(date) with inner join and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have 2 tables, user and order.
Both name and group in user table form a unique combination, so note that here we have total of 5 unique combination in the entries.
For each unique combination, i would like to find their latest respective status, only concern about active and inactive.
Then, I'll ignore the active status, and output query with the inactive status.
(but currently, im only query for all active/inactive results because i dont want to make things more difficult)

[image: sample]
Here are two closest sql statement ive written (wrong)
this returns all unique combination with status:active/inactive

```
SELECT order.id, order.status, order.someA, order.someB, order.someC, order.date, user.name, user.group, user.site FROM order INNER JOIN user ON user.id = order.id WHERE (status = 'P' OR status = 'F');
```

this only give first entry of active/inactive for each unique combination (should be last/latest entry)

```
SELECT MAX(order.date), order.date, order.id, order.status, order.someA, order.someB, order.someC, user.name, user.group, user.site FROM order INNER JOIN user ON user.id = order.id WHERE site = 'US' AND (status = 'P' OR status = 'F') GROUP BY name, group ORDER BY date;
```

id  name    group   site
K01 John    Texas   US
K02 Niall   Ohio    US
K03 sally   Ohio    US
K04 Simon   Ohio    US
K05 James   Texas   US
K06 James   Texas   US
K07 John    Texas   US

id  status  someA   someB   someC   date (timestamp)
K01 active  I   just    randomly    21-09-2018  19:22:33 PM
K02 inactive    put some    words   22-09-2018  16:22:33 PM
K03 active  here    for this    22-09-2018  19:22:33 PM
K04 unknown dummy   example output  22-09-2018  19:22:33 PM
K05 inactive    X   S   V   23-09-2018  19:22:33 PM
K06 unknown hope    i   explain 23-09-2018  19:22:33 PM
K07 unknown my  question    well    24-09-2018  19:22:33 PM

The data above is tab-delimited, let me know if it's not able to import into excel.
welcome to edit my sentences, I might not have the perfect sentence to describe my question.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), and note that both `order` and  `group` are reserved words.

Comment: @Strawberry, thank you for telling me those two were reserved words, im just using it for this dummy. I should be careful next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the most recent order, you can do:

```
select . . .   -- unclear what columns you really want
from users u join
     orders o
     on u.id = o.id
where (u.name, u.group, o.date) in
       (select u2.name, u2.group, max(o2.date)
        from users u2 join
             orders o2
             on u2.id = o2.id
        group by u2.name, u2.group
       ) and
       o.status <> 'active';
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I'll try it when i got the access to sql which i dont have now, hmm, the columns i want to return is in desired output aka the third table in excel.

Comment: hi @Gordon, strangely it return nothing with no errors. I am sure there should be matching entries . :(

Comment: @Santa . .  If it returns no rows and no error, then there are no matches.  The issue is probably the filtering on "active".  Try without that condition.